# YOLO loss function width and height component explanation

Tags: neural-networks, object-detection, yolo

I am reading this paper on how yolo defines loss function.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640

I did research on other posts, but these posts did not seem to answer my confusion: ([How to calculate the class probability of a grid cell in YOLO object detection algorithm?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276204/how-to-calculate-the-class-probability-of-a-grid-cell-in-yolo-object-detection-a) & [Yolo Loss function explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287486/yolo-loss-function-explanation/287497))

> Sum-squared error also equally weights errors in large boxes and small
>   boxes. Our error metric should reflect that small deviations in large
>   boxes matter less than in small boxes. To partially address this we
>   predict the square root of the bounding box width and height instead
>   of the width and height directly.

[image]

I could not make myself clear why applying square root could help resolve the case Sum-squared error also equally weights errors in large boxes and small boxes and give me any intuitions if possible!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you for the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition or the goal is that **regression errors relative to their respective bounding box size should matter roughly equally**. E.g. a 5px deviation on a 500px wide box should have less of an effect on the loss as a 5px deviation in a 20px wide box. The square root downscales high values while less affecting low values of width and height.

The *normal* sum of squared errors will just punish the deviation independent of the size of the box.

Answer (score 0):

[YOLOv1 from Scratch](https://youtu.be/n9_XyCGr-MI?list=PLhhyoLH6Ijfw0TpCTVTNk42NN08H6UvNq&t=2121) explains as below. It also explains other considerations made in the loss function design.

> Lets say we have a very large bounding box and we take those subtracts and squared, that squared will be very large. But for a small bounding box, the loss will not be as large.
>
> So what they do is to take the square root to make sure we prioritise smaller bounding boxes equally as much as we do for large bounding boxes.

[image]

Taking square root before square reduces the loss impacts due to the bounding box sizes.